# unable to update sqlite3 on mac osx?

Tags: sqlite, macos, updating

i want to install newest sqlite3 on my mac osx. i am trying this from last 6 hours but still not succeed.Here are the steps i have followed.I have tried this site

mkdir ~/src
cd ~/src
curl http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-3.6.18.tar.gz | tar zx
cd sqlite-3.6.18
autoconf
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install

//check what version of SQLite is installed
sqlite3 --version
 3.6.18

which sqlite3
 /usr/local/bin/sqlite3

but it fails

but i manually downloaded the sqlite3 from the address below
http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-amalgamation-3.6.22.tar.gz

and then tried the above scriot

the description of the above link is

A tarball containing the amalgamation  together with an configure script and makefile for building it. This is the recommended source distribution for all Unix and Unix-like platforms.

and i have also downloaded the

Precompiled Binaries For Mac OS X
    sqlite3-3.6.22-osx-x86.zip
A command-line program for accessing and modifying SQLite version 3.* databases. For x86 Macs running Leopard (OS 10.5) only.

but still i am unable to install.I have also read that modifying the default sqlite3 will cause some application stopped working because apple has a modified version of sqlite.

does some one knows how do i install the new sqlite3 and use that without removing the default one.I am not familiar with terminal commands.

ok here is an update
i have installed the sqlite in a new folder in /users/admin/sqlite3new
but when i run sqlite3 from terminal it shows older version...

also if i directly executes the bin file i am unable to open database is there any other way to open database?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Macports](http://www.macports.org/) ships a version of sqlite3 that will probably work perfectly fine (and it installs your dependencies automagically). Maybe that's an option for you?

Macports by default installs software in `/opt` so it will not remove the 'default' sqlite.

Comment: i have installed the sqlite in a new folder in /users/admin/sqlite3new
but when i run sqlite3 from terminal it shows older version...

also if i directly executes the bin file i am unable to open database is there any other way to open database?